# Make mysql query faster

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this query which takes around 29 second to perform and need to make it faster. I have created index on aggregate_date column and still no real improvement. Each aggregate_date has almost 26k rows within the table.
One more thing the query will run starting from 1/1/2018 till yesterday date

```
select MAX(os.aggregate_date) as lastMonthDay,
       os.totalYTD
from (
    SELECT aggregate_date,
           Sum(YTD) AS totalYTD
    FROM tbl_aggregated_tables
    WHERE subscription_type = 'Subcription Income'
    GROUP BY aggregate_date
) as os
GROUP by MONTH(os.aggregate_date), YEAR(os.aggregate_date);
```

I used Explain Select ... and received the following [image]

**update**

The most of query time is consumed by the inner Query, so as scaisEdge suggested bellow i have tested the query and the time is reduced to almost 8s.
the Inner Query will look like:

```
select agt.aggregate_date,SUM(YTD) 
      from tbl_aggregated_tables as agt
      FORCE INDEX(idx_aggregatedate_subtype_YTD)
      WHERE agt.subscription_type = 'Subcription Income'
      GROUP by agt.aggregate_date
```

I have noticed that this comparison "WHERE agt.subscription_type = 'Subcription Income'" takes the most of time. So is there any way to change that and to be mentioned the column of subscription_type only have 2 values which is 'Subcription Income' and 'Subcription Unit'

Comment: try to run `explain select...`(add `explain` to your query) and post the result.

Comment: @Narro i have posted the pic of explain.

Comment: If you look at second line, possible key says aggregateDate and subscriptionType. Can you try adding a composite index of these two and see if it make any difference ? Also can you try adding an index on subscription type for the inner query?

Comment: composite index is already there for aggregateDate and subscriptionType, now I'm adding an index to subscriptionType

Comment: how is the inner query performance? i think you need an index `(subscription_type,aggregate_date)`(column order is important) for table `tbl_aggregated_tables`.

Comment: @K.M.FazleAzimBabu 2 seconds down only.

Comment: Technically, totalytd should be part of your outer group by

Comment: @Strawberry I'm getting the sum of all YTD within a date. so it should be in the first select.

Answer (score 1):

The index  on `aggregate_date` column is not useful for performance because in not involved  in where condition
looking to your code an useful index should be on column `subscription_type`

you could try using a redundant index adding also the column involved  in select clause   (for try to obtain all the data in query from index avoiding access  to table)so you index could be

```
create idx1 on tbl_aggregated_tables (subscription_type, aggregate_date, YTD )
```

the meaning of the last group by seems not coherent with the select clause

Comment: i have done that and the performance is optimized a bit with 21s but could you please explain the last point " the meaning of the last group by seems not coherent with the select clause ". Many thanks

Comment: for the not coherent  ..  you have a group by  ..  but seems to me that you want just single rows  result..  so if this is true why you use a unuseful goup by ??

Comment: nope, let me explain what this query do, at the first select I'm grouping to get the sum of YTD as each day has around 26k for each product. On the second grouping i wanted just want to get the max date of each month of a year. ex 31/1/2018 is the max day of January in 2018. so its not a single row result.